# ToggleButton changes state when switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, togglebutton

So basically i have a togglebutton in a fragment, the thing is that if i check it(true), whenever I switch to another fragment, and then "come back", the state doesnt save, and i have to check it again, what i want to do is the toggle button to remember its state even after switching fragments.
Thanks, hope someone helps.

Here is the code:

```
    cocina.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){

                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).on2();



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else{
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).off2();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using static values as much as possible so the value could survive the app Lifecycle. I'd put the boolean value in `SharedPreference` and retrieve it back `onCreateView` of the `Fragment` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();


cocina.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean("switchValue", true).commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else{
            editor.putBoolean("switchValue", false).commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

and to retrieve the value whenever you needs it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean default = sharedPref.getBoolean("switchValue", false);
```

Comment: where my code should i put this line: boolean default = sharedPref.getBoolean("switchValue", false); ?inside the fragment too?

Comment: I'd say in the `onCreateView` of your Fragment, then do cocina.setChecked(default), just before setting the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a static boolean the value of which will be set to true or false accordingly the state of the toogle Switch. And on create view of fragment you can apply the condition that if boolean b(say) is false so Switch.setChecked(b).

Comment: I think it shouldn't be static as in that case every instance of the fragment class, so basically any fragment, will share the same value, which might not be desirable. Other wise yes, a boolean in you code to save the state of the check box is probably your easier way around it.

Comment: Yes I guess I am mistaken. SharedPref would be the preferred way of doing it.